# Changing language in drupal

Tags: hooks

So my problem is i dont know how to make my custom menu item change language in drupal. I know there is a language switcher in drupal, but i want to make a new custom menu in drupal, theme it, and i want the links to trigger changing the language, like the link "french" changes the site to french. How can this custom trigger of events be created in drupal and how do i know which functions to call/variables to change to allow me to achieve this?

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score -1):

May be you are looking for [language_negotiation_get_switch_links](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!language.inc/function/language_negotiation_get_switch_links/7)

> Return the language switch links for the given language.

```
$path = drupal_is_front_page() ? '<front>' : $_GET['q'];
$links = language_negotiation_get_switch_links($type, $path);
```

Comment: The question is not asking about the language switcher links; it's asking about localizing menu items and content.

Comment: Above question is indeed talking about language switching links... "I know there is a language switcher in drupal, but i want to make a new custom menu in drupal, theme it, and i want the links to trigger changing the language, like the link "french" changes the site to french."

Comment: Oh, you're right. I misread that - sorry.  I must have been thinking about something else at the time.

Answer (score -1):

If you have localized content, say an "About Us" page with and English version and a version of that page translated into French, then you're looking for [Entity Translation](http://drupal.org/project/entity_translation).

You don't need to create a custom menu item as the Locale module, which ET depends on, provides this block for you.  It should be called "Language switcher".